# Divert request to different server as per request-url in NGINX

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I want to achieve something like lined out below, but I couldn't find a possibility:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location /get-product {
        if(request=GET){  
            proxy_pass http://get-app-server:8080/products;
            proxy_set_header Host "get-app-server";
        }
        if(request=POST){  
            proxy_pass http://post-app-server:8080/products;
            proxy_set_header Host "post-app-server";
        }
    }
}
```

How could I implement such a decision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of possible solutions. For example, using a fake internal URI (`/post/get-product`) to handle one of the two cases:

```
location /get-product {
    if ($request_method = POST) {
        rewrite ^ /post$uri last;
    }
    proxy_pass http://get-app-server:8080/products;
    proxy_set_header Host "get-app-server";
}
location /post/get-product {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://post-app-server:8080/products;
    proxy_set_header Host "post-app-server";
}
```

Note the correct syntax and variable name for the `if` statement.